# Deleting duplicates based on latest revision in SQL

Tags: sql, duplicates

I'm having a bit of an SQL head-scratching moment and was wondering if anyone could help. Using this data (for example):

```
workId     rateRevision
1          1
1          2
1          3
2          1
3          1
3          2
4          1
4          2
4          3
```

... I basically want to delete all duplicates except the latest revision (highest rateRevision value). So I would end up with:

```
workId     rateRevision
1          3
2          1
3          2
4          3
```

Theoretically it sounds really simple but I can't work it out in SQL. Here's my current code:

```
SELECT * FROM rate r
WHERE r.rateRevision = 
(select r.rateRevision from rate r ORDER BY r.rateRevision DESC LIMIT 1);
```

...but that just returns

```
workId     rateRevision
4          3
```

Of course, this is only selecting the values at the moment, but I was planning on essentially just reversing it for the delete statement. Does anyone have any ideas please?

Many thanks!
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like:

```
delete from rate r where r.rateRevision < (select max(r2.rateRevision) from rate r2 where r.workId = r2.workId)
```

Comment: Thank you Chris, that worked perfectly. Using max() should have been blindingly obvious haha. Appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
select workId, MAX(rateRevision) as MaxRevision
from MyTable
group by workId
```

Results:

```
workId  MaxRevision
1       3
2       1
3       2
4       3
```

Chris gave you the best & simplest answer I think.  If you have a trickier situation where you want to remove duplicates (e.g. keep the 5 most recent revisions, delete all the rest), you can use a CTE to add an Ordinal "row number", something like this.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT workId, 
           rateRevision,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY workId ORDER BY rateRevision DESC) AS Ordinal
    FROM MyTable
)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE Ordinal > 5   -- You can keep the top "N" records (here we are just keeping the top 5)
```

Comment: Thank you John, this method was probably also appropriate but I ended up going for Chris'. Once again, thanks for the help :)

Comment: Cheers for the additional comment- I've never experimented with CTE before. I would give you a vote up if I had the reputation. But you will have to just imagine basking in its votey glory!